# Java RMI ClassNotFoundException on the client side

Tags: java, intellij-idea, rmi, classnotfoundexception

There have been several questions with this same Title, but none of them have helped me solve my issue.

I have been trying to follow the tutorial here:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/overview.html

I was driving myself crazy by putting everything in one project, so I've created 3 separate projects:

1. Server -> It has Main (Driver), and class:ServerNode implements Compute
2. Client -> It has Main (Driver), and class:TestTask implements Task
3. Shared -> It has interface:Task, and interface:Compute

The idea is... both applications need to know about the Interfaces Task (The unit of work the client sends to the server), and Compute (Which is the interface of ServerNode that the client uses to give commands to).

Server Code:

```
System.setProperty("java.security.policy","file:server.policy");
    System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.security.policy"));

    if (System.getSecurityManager() == null) {
        System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());
    }
    int port = 1099;
    try {
        LocateRegistry.createRegistry(port);
        String name = "Compute"; // Name of the interface
        Compute engine = new ServerNode(); // Implementor of Compute interface, ComputeEngine
        Compute stub =
                (Compute) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(engine, 0); // Create the stub the client will use
        Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(port);
        registry.bind(name, stub);   // Bind the "Compute" to the stub, so client can access it by "Compute"
        System.out.println("ComputeEngine bound");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("ComputeEngine exception:");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Client Code:

```
System.out.println("Entering client");
    String lookupName = "localhost";
    System.setProperty("java.security.policy","file:client.policy");
    System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.security.policy"));
    System.setProperty("rmi.server.codebase", "file:/c:/Users/Brian/Documents/RMI_ClientSide/TestTask.class");
    System.out.println(System.getProperty("rmi.server.codebase"));
    if (System.getSecurityManager() == null) {
        System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());
    }
    try {
        String name = "Compute";



        Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry("localhost", 1099);

        Compute comp99 = (Compute)registry.lookup("Compute");

        System.out.println(comp99.executeTask(new TestTask()));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("ComputePi exception:");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I am led to believe, from the tutorial
That only the CLIENT needs to know about TestTask... It doesn't/shouldn't need to go in Shared. The server just needs to know about the interface Task and the client gives it an implementor of that interface... I believe in the background the server downloads the concrete code from the clients codebase.

My directory structure is
1. Documents/RMI_ServiceSide
2. Documents/RMI_ClientSide
3. Documents/RMI_Shared

Right now I am programmatically starting up the rmiregister in the server code, instead of running it on the command line. I don't think that's my problem, but at this point (after 4 hours of debugging) I have no idea. I am able to start the server though with that code.

The problem is on the client side. When I try to run the client code, I get:

```
Entering client
file:client.policy
file:/c:/Users/Brian/Documents/RMI_ClientSide/TestTask.class
ComputePi exception:
java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
    java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.company.TestTask
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:355)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:276)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:253)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:162)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:227)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:179)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.executeTask(Unknown Source)
    at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.company.TestTask
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:315)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.company.TestTask
```

Alright, it appears that when I try to execute the TestTask, the Registry comes back that it can't find it. I have tried every possible combination of paths for the -Djava.rmi.server.codebase=file:/c:/Users/Brian/Documents/RMI_ClientSide/   command line argument AND/OR the System.setProperty("rmi.server.codebase", "file:/c:/Users/Brian/Documents/RMI_ClientSide/TestTask.class");

Absolutely nothing seems to work... I don't know if this is an issue with the rmiregistry or if I just didn't hit the correct permutation on my codebase. This is all on one machine, so I don't know why it is having problems finding it.

To be explicit... The files that would be necessary:
1. Client -> RMI_ClientSide/bin/.../Main.class and TestTask.class
2. Server -> RMI_ServerSide/bin/..Main.class and ServerNode.class
3. Shared -> RMI_Shared/bin/.../RMI_Shared.jar -> contains Task.class and Compute.class

As I said, these are three separate projects, BUT the package name is the same... package com.company; Just by coincidence, I didn't rename the default when creating each project. I don't know if that matters either. Certainly didn't when importing RMI_Shared.jar into server and client projects... they both compiled fine.

One other answer I found gave the impression Shared would need to contain the TestTask too... but that doesn't make sense as the registry should pull the class definition up to the server when needed... That way a client can execute arbitrary code up to the server (Which is intended in this simple insecure test).

I would appreciate any help to get this running. Thanks!

EDIT: Added a link to my codebase folder image
[Codebase directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2p8p.png)

Note that the directories for my projects themselves are just documents/. Client, server, and helper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread
```

The class is not found *at the server.* You sent an instance of `com.company.TestTask` but the server doesn't have that class on its CLASSPATH and cannot find it via the codebase feature.

```
System.setProperty("rmi.server.codebase", "file:/c:/Users/Brian/Documents/RMI_ClientSide/TestTask.class");
```

Your codebase string is wrong. It should not include the class file name or any directory that is part of its package. A codebase is a list of URLs that are either JAR files or directories that are heads of package structures.

Comment: Thanks for the comment - This conflicts with my understanding of https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/compiling.html:   This example separates the interfaces, remote object implementation, and client code into three packages:

compute – Compute and Task interfaces
engine – ComputeEngine implementation class
client – ComputePi client code and Pi task implementation

Comment: Note how their "Pi" class implements "Task"... The Compute package is their shared package... note how both the client and server compilations use that Compute.jar. BUT, the server DOES NOT use the client package (Which contains the definition of "Pi"). This is to say, why does the server need the concrete TestTask implementation when it knows the Task interface. Isnt the registry/RMI supposed to pull that code from the clients codebase?

Comment: The server will pull the class from the client codebase if it can, but your client JVM codebase is a file: URL pointing to a location in the client filesystem, which means nothing at the server. Codebase URLs are usually HTTP or FTP.

Comment: I completely agree if Server and Client were on separate machines, but in this simple test case they are not. I simply spin up a Server process (java -jar RMI_ServerSide.jar) and a client (java -jar RMI_ClientSide.jar) and target "localhost". They both share the same filesystem so should be able to get that file. If that simply won't work, though, I'll have to figure out how to host the files via http/ftp (Which is the long term anyway).

Comment: Your codebase string is wrong. It should not include the class file name or any directory that is part of its package. A codebase is a list of URLs that are either JAR files or directories that are heads of package structures.

Comment: I tried to refactor a bit... I compiled the client Project (Main, TestTask) into RMI_ClientSide.jar. I also have the RMI_Shared.jar. I stuck them both in C:\Users\brian\Documents\RMI_Codebase. These are some things I tried in client: System.setProperty("rmi.client.codebase", "file:/c:/Users/brian/Documents/RMI_Codebase/RMI_ClientSide.jar");     I also tried System.setProperty("rmi.client.codebase", "file:/c:/Users/brian/Documents/RMI_Codebase/");    and of course -Djava.rmi.server.codebase=file:/c:/Users/brian/Documents/RMI_Codebase/    Any ideas?

Comment: The first one (with RMI_ClientSide.jar) should work, if RMI_ClientSide.jar contains TestTask.class in the appropriate directory for its package.

Comment: It does not, tried programmatically and with jvm arguments (both, and with one or the other). However, now that I know what SHOULD work, I can keep looking at why it isn't... it might be because all three projects have the same (default) package name of com.company. I'm going to remake all three once again w/different package names and see if it works. Thanks again for your help, this has been frustrating because it seems like it should work.